# Утечка памяти, как бороться C#

Tags: c#, com

Коллеги, здравствуйте! Имею вот такой код. Идет постоянная утечка памяти, поскольку через данное соединение передаются jpeg'ги. Как лучше всего чистить память?

```
public static V83.COMConnector com1s = new V83.COMConnector(); //{ get { return com1s;   }  set { com1s = value; } } 

dynamic res1c { get; set; } //Временная переменная для соединения

public static dynamic Connect1c(string Server1c, string Base1c, string login1c, string password1c, out string status1)
{
    // dynamic result;
    string StrConnect = "Srvr='" + Server1c + "';Ref='" + Base1c + "';Usr='" + login1c + "';Pwd='" + password1c + "';";
    dynamic result1;
    com1s.PoolCapacity = 10;
    com1s.PoolTimeout = 60;

    try
    {
        result1 = com1s.Connect(StrConnect);
        // Проверка соединения
        var FunctionQry = result1.МобильныйМастерПриемщик.ПолучитьXML("ВЫБРАТЬ  ИСТИНА");

        // Передаем ссылку обратно.
        status1 = "OK";
        return result1;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        status1 = "ERROR:1C:" + ex.Message;
        result1 = null;
        return result1;
    }
}
```

Comment: В коде, который вы привели, нету передачи картинок. Приведите релевантный код в вопросе.

Answer (score 4):

Проблема связана с тем, что сборщик мусора (Garbage Collector, GC) может высвободить память неиспользуемыми COM-объектами (*а проблема, очевидно, именно в них*) не сразу, даже в том случае, если GC был запущен по признаку нехватки памяти. 
Более того, даже принудительный вызов сборщика (`GC.Collect()`) не гарантирует высвобождение памяти, занимаемой неиспользуемым более COM-объектом.

Существуют два механизма для гарантированного высвобождения памяти, занимаемой COM-объектами: через `AppDomain` и через метод `ReleaseComObject`.

Использование AppDomain'а с точки зрения процессорного времени весьма дорогостояще, на фоне чего метод ReleaseComObject является оптимальным вариантом.

Попробуйте вот такой код для освобождения памяти:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(com1s);
```

При выполнении обратите внимание на возвращаемое этим методов значение int: если оно ненулевое, значит, на объект еще остались ссылки. В этом случае (а можно и сразу использовать именно такую реализацию) вызывайте метод в цикле до тех пор, пока ссылок на объект не останется:

```
int refCount;
do
   refCount = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(com1s);
while (refCount > 0);
```

Comment: `public static V83.COMConnector com1s = new V83.COMConnector();` - `com1s` is `static` - Поэтому он может быть released только, когда приложение выгружается. A утечка памяти, похоже, происходит во время работы.

Comment: @user270576, верное замечание касательно `static`: действительно, статичные объекты не собираются сборщиком вообще (т.е. статичные существуют на всем протяжении жизни AppDomain'а), так в данном случае `GC.Collect` лишен смысла вовсе. Однако вызов `ReleaseComObject` корректно работает в том числе и со статичными объектами.

Comment: Я просто хотел сказать, что проблема, скорее всего, не с _com1s_, а с теми COM-объектами, которые созданы _com1s_ (и не released). Использование `ReleaseComObject` - полностью правильно.

Answer (score 1):

если *com1s* является COM-объектом, то возможно, что *result1* также является COM-объектом (Почему он dynamic-то?), а вы никогда не отпускаете этот com-объект - не в этом фрагменте кода, в любом случае. Так что есть утечка памяти.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую...